# Do I need ETA or transit visa if I have a 5 hr transit by air at Toronto airport?

Tags: canada, transit-visas, eta, air-canada, yyz

I am citizen of India (Indian passport holder) with a valid F-1 visa and work permit (EAD card) with me. I have an Air Canada flight from Delhi to LA via Toronto so I have a 5 hr transit at the airport. I am not planning to go out of the airport. Do I still need a transit visa or eTA to board my flight to LA? If yes, which one do I need? I have already checked this [link](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp) and doesn't specify what type of visa do I need (eTA or transit). Also, it doesn't take into account that I am a valid US Visa holder.

Comment: ETA is not a visa, so if you need a visa, eTA will not suffice.  The tool does not take your US visa into account because it is not relevant.  US status is relevant only for US citizens and green card holders.

Comment: You are confused. You were not refused because you did not have a visa for India, but because you didn't have a visa for Canada. Having a US Visa does not grant you ability to transit through Canada. See answers below.

Comment: The edit to this question changes it utterly from the original - the edit should never have been approved and this new question should be submitted as a fresh question.

Comment: Reverted edit as per my previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You need to apply for a Canadian Transit Visa.  From the [Immigration and Citizenship Canada's website](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/transit-apply-who.asp?lnktrk=visa_transit_air)

> You need a transit visa if you are from a visa-required country and:
>
> > your international flight stops at a Canadian airport on its way to another country
> >
> > you will be connecting between two international flights at a Canadian airport
>
> Some people can transit through Canada without a visa if they are travelling to or from the United States. Find out if you can transit without a visa.

[Since India is not a Visa-Exempt country](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-all.asp) and [Indian citizens are ineligible for Transit Without a Visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/twov/travellers.asp) you are required to obtain a transit visa.

Other users have pointed out that there exists a sterile transit corridor at Toronto Pearson and that you do not need to present yourself to a Canadian CBSA agent during your transit, however both your airline and the US CBP agent will likely enforce the transit visa requirement.

Answer (score -3):

The airport has a handy [connecting guide](https://www.torontopearson.com/Connecting.aspx#), you should input your airlines there to see your requirements. It appears that as long as you arrive and leave through the same terminal, there is no requirement to present yourself to the CBSA (Canadian Border Security Agency), only US CBP.

I have checked International arrival on Air Canada to US departure on Air Canada, and it appears that that is OK.

Comment: According to the transit without visa (TWOV) page, a traveler transiting at terminal 1 must also be a national of one of a small list of countries, not including India, to qualify.  See http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/twov/travellers.asp.

Comment: The information in this question is factually correct but does not provide an answer to the question asked.  The answer to the question asked is that yes, you require a valid Canadian Transit Visa.